# How to structure my query for a MS Access Chart?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office

This is probably an easy one for a guru here.

I have a datatable of employee results by month structured into the following fields:

```
Name,Metric,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr, ...,Dec
```

When I take this dataset as is, and select it all as an input for a simple column graph in **MS Excel**, the chart figures out that each series is defined by Name+Metric, the (y-axis) is the defined by the values in Jan-Dec columns, and the columns of the graph are split by date (x-axis).

When I feed this same dataset into MS Access with a simple `Select` query:

```
Select Name, Metric, Jan, Feb, Mar... Dec from Results
```

I need to be able to tell the chart how to use the data.  How do I do this?

Also, I know that I could flatten the dataset so the dates are in rows, and then use a `Crosstab query` for Access to figure it out, but it seems inefficient to condense the data so that Access can just expand it out again.  I'm going to assume there is a way to tell the chart somehow how to use the data, which is what I am looking for in an answer here.

Comment: What kind of chart are you shooting for here?

Comment: Bar graph... the results are simple counts of orders by employee, by month.  There are 3 order types.  I have a filter in place for each employee.  For a given employee, I want a bar graph to show the data with 3 series (for each order type) by month.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

This is a quick and dirty fix.

Excel essentially is creating 'grouped' categories of Name + Metric via concatenation. A quick and dirty solution is to use the default bar chart and set its Row Source property to:

Select Name & ' ' & Metric, Jan, Feb, Mar... Dec from Results

After that if it still needs adjustment, double click on the chart object from design view and see what chart properties you can mess around with.

#### Option 2

For more advanced control of the chart layout, select your table Results and mess around with the PivotChart function in Access. This chart can later be added as a subform on another report or form.

*side note: you should try to avoid the field name "Name" since it is a reserved word*

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to tell access how to interpret the dataset, but from what it sounds like, we are constrained that the first column defines the series names?

Comment: There is a little bit more you can do in the chart editor (e.g. tell it to skip columns, use rows instead of columns, etc) but I am pretty sure that grouped series is not possible in the chart control - either concatenate manually or use a pivot chart